# Keyboard Navigation in GNOME 3 "Overview" Mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

In Gnome3, when I've switched to overview mode (by pressing the "super" button), how do I navigate between thumbnail images of windows with my keyboard? How do I then select a window?  Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNOME Shell currently (up to 3.4) does not support keyboard navigation natively. There already are a few [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644306) reports filed, but for now try the [Window Navigator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/windownavigator/) or [Window selector](https://github.com/tanwald/gnome-shell-extension-arrow-key-window-selector) extensions. And of course, good old <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Upd: GNOME Shell 3.12 allows focusing the window thumbnails as any other widget, so they can be selected using keyboard and the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.